# Macro for text-to-columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a code to do the following:

1. Using text-to-columns,the data should get divided in different columns.
   The data in Cells A1-A8 is like this:

[image]

This data should appear in different columns.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code, then we can try and help you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Community likes when you show what you've done so far. Please, provide us your examples, your expected result, and the community will surely help you.

Comment: Range("A1:A8").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :=":", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
Sub Macro()
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :=":", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), 
End Sub
```

Comment: I've 20,000 files in which this editing is required.. Is there is any way to Run this macro on all of these files automatically.

Comment: Did you get it fixed? Been on holiday.

Comment: yes... recorded macro worked well in this case.thanks

Comment: Can i run this macro on 1000+ files kept in a folder without one-by-one opening them manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can build the FieldInfo parameter dynamically by building out the string. In the example below, there are 10 resultant columns. The For loop builds the sFieldInfo variable, and specifies all the columns in Text format.

```
sComma = ""
sFieldInfo = ""
For x = 1 To 10
    sFieldInfo = sFieldInfo & sComma & " Array(" & x & ", xlTextFormat)"
    sComma = ","
Next x

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("J5"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="/", _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(sFieldInfo)
```